# Transaction Errors - Am I asking too much?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, transactions, ado.net

I am running the following loop in vb.net, which over 1000's of iterations issues 1000's of update commands:

```
Dim updateRoute As String = "UPDATE [Routes] SET [matching_route_id] = ? WHERE [ID] = ?"
Using transaction As OleDbTransaction = myconnection.BeginTransaction()
    Dim id As Integer
    For Each id In ids
        Using cmd2 As New OleDbCommand(updateRoute, myconnection)
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", id)
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", id)
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    Next
    transaction.Commit()
End Using
```

And yet I am getting the following exceptions

> ExecuteNonQuery requires the command to have a transaction when the
>   connection assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction.
>   The Transaction property of the command has not been initialized.

Which seems to tell me I need to begin a transaction at each iteration of `cmd2` coming into existence. To me, this blows away any reason of using transactions -- as I would like to do this as a big batch. I.e., the transaction should start prior to the first UPDATE and end at the last UPDATE statement.

So I guess my question is two-fold:

1. How do I get vb.net to accept my transaction before the loop
2. Or, how do I run a big batch update like this. Currently, one row updating at a time is almost prohibitively too slow.

Comment: you dont need a new command each iteration, just new param values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to associate the command to the transaction, for sample:

```
Using cmd2 As New OleDbCommand(updateRoute, myconnection, transaction)
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", id)
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", id)
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

On the other hand, you should guarantee a `RollBack` if the `Commit` fails using a `Try/Catch` block, for sample:

```
Using transaction As OleDbTransaction = myconnection.BeginTransaction()
    Try     
        Dim id As Integer
        For Each id In ids
            Using cmd2 As New OleDbCommand(updateRoute, myconnection, transaction)
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", id)
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", id)
                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
        Next
        transaction.Commit()
    Catch
        transaction.RollBack();
    End Try     
End Using
```

### Updates

I'm not sure but maybe if you hit in a single query on the database, it can improve the performance. Or, just implement a loop between each `100` ids and execute `100` updates in a single hit per time, can improve the performance.

```
Using transaction As OleDbTransaction = myconnection.BeginTransaction()
    Try     
        Dim id As Integer
        Dim b As New StringBuilder()

        For Each id In ids
            b.AppendFormat("UPDATE [Routes] SET [matching_route_id] = {0} WHERE [ID] = {0}; ", id)
        Next

        Using cmd2 As New OleDbCommand(updateRoute, myconnection, transaction)              
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
        transaction.Commit()
    Catch
        transaction.RollBack();
    End Try     
End Using
```

Comment: Nice! It works but the process is still painfully slow. Is there a better way to do mass updates?

Comment: Maybe you can get some improvements with a stored procedure and just call it from the ado.net. I never tried using the batch updates from ado.net, but take a look. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbbwt18a(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Would it be possible to create the `cmd2` variable once, then place the for-loop inside the `Using cmd2...` statement? This way its only created once but its transactions are set at each loop iteration

Comment: If you do that, you have to clear the parameter and replace with the new values. I think you could hit on the database once, but I'm not sure if you can take a good performance. I'll update it.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach to try catch

```
      Using transaction As OleDbTransaction = myconnection.BeginTransaction()            
        Dim id As Integer
        Dim errors as Integer = 0

        For Each id In ids
            Using cmd2 As New OleDbCommand(updateRoute, myconnection, transaction)
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", id)
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", id)

                Try 
                  cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Catch
                  errors+=1
                End Try
            End Using
        Next

        If errors=0
          transaction.Commit()
        else
          transaction.RollBack();
        End If    
      End Using
```